# grails how do I call one controllers action and embed the resulting view in another controller

Tags: grails, sitemesh

Say I have controllers **Author** and **Book** like this:

```
class Author{
 def show(Integer authorId){
     //code
  render view:'show',model:[author:author]
 }
}

class Book{
 def list(Integer authorId){
 //code
 render view:'list', model:[books:books]
}
}
```

Now when render show page of an author I want to show the list of books the author wrote,and I want to do it just by calling the Book's controller list action by passing the authorId.

*Is it possible to do so? if yes how?*

Answer (score 0):

**simple**!

With in `show.gsp` of **Author** do this:

```
<g:include controller = "book" action="list" id="${authorInstance?.id}" />
```

[For detail here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/include.html)